What is the difference between vectorization vs semantic structuring of data when inputting such data into a prompt?
For example you have data in a mark down file structured in a semantic way via something like the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM but then you wanted to 'vectorize' this document instead, where I presume; 1. would this then be better way to input the data in a Large Language Model? such as ChatGPT for example?, with the end result being a JSON file that has been vectorized Below is some example code I generated not great python code but just to show what I mean by vectorization:
import json
import nltk
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
import torch

# Sample text
text = "Solar energy is renewable and reduces carbon emissions. It can lower electricity bills for households. Solar panels require sunlight to generate power, which can be intermittent."

# Step 1: Chunk the Content
def chunk_text(text, chunk_size=512):
    nltk.download('punkt')
    sentences = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)
    chunks = []
    current_chunk = []

    for sentence in sentences:
        current_chunk.append(sentence)
        if sum(len(s) for s in current_chunk) >= chunk_size:
            chunks.append(' '.join(current_chunk))
            current_chunk = []

    if current_chunk:
        chunks.append(' '.join(current_chunk))

    return chunks

# Step 2: Vectorize the Text
def vectorize_text(chunks):
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

    vectors = []
    for chunk in chunks:
        inputs = tokenizer(chunk, return_tensors='pt', truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=512)
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        # Use the embeddings from the last hidden state
        vector = outputs.last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).squeeze().detach().numpy()
        vectors.append(vector.tolist())

    return vectors

# Step 3: Output to JSON
def output_to_json(chunks, vectors, output_file):
    data = {
        "chunks": [{"chunk": chunk, "vector": vector} for chunk, vector in zip(chunks, vectors)]
    }
    with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

# Main function
def main():
    chunks = chunk_text(text)
    vectors = vectorize_text(chunks)
    output_to_json(chunks, vectors, 'output.json')

# Run the main function
main()

What is the difference between vectorization vs semantic structuring when inputting such data into a prompt?
I had a look at this question: File format for generating error-free structured data with LLMs but I feel this is potentially over convoluted and not really answering my questions here?


would this then be better way to input the data in a Large Language Model? such as ChatGPT for example?

LLMs expect texts in the prompt, not vectors corresponding to their embeddings. If the question is about how to vectorize a text, standard LLMs aren't made for that: use a text embedding model instead or tweak the LLM to get embeddings from it eg see the LLM2vec and ULLME: A Unified Framework for Large Language Model Embeddings with Generation-Augmented Learning.

So I have misunderstood, theres no dynamic towards inputting vectorised data say into ChatGPT I need to look at a different model or approach to that. Makes sense if so. That paper you linked is useful, many thanks!
